# Sqlite Query to get the details

Tags: database, sqlite

Hi Let the table be as,

```
id      Name
1102    n_1102/abc
1102    n_1102/xyz
1102    n_1102/pqr
```

Please help to get the following data from the table,

for each id, we have many names, but from the name, the first part ie. before '/' is common for all, so if i query as

**"Select Name from table where id = 1102"**, i will get all the details, but i want only the first common part in all the names.

i.e by executing a query for id = 1102, then i should i get name as n_1102 as a single row in the result set.

Comment: your question is not about sqlite!  you  just need a subString of your name

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to select the portion of the `name` occurring before the backslash for a given `id`, but you only want to return one of them.  You can try the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTR(name, 1, INSTR(name, '/') - 1)
FROM yourTable
WHERE id = 1102
```

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Do you know how `DISTINCT` works?  Based on the sample data, we don't need `LIMIT 1`.